# Android read of intent extra value for changes

Tags: php, html, dom

I am wondering if there is any way to 'listen' for changes in an Intent Extra value, beside doing a continuous read of it

I explain, i have to call intent actions(lets say a1, a2, a3) and then call a specific intent action for an extra representing the result(lets say action a4) of the previously called action, however the result may become available only after 30 seconds and up, i never know when.

So far i am calling, in a loop, the intent action(a4) for the result of the previously called actions(a1, a2, a3), but i was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Intent Extra, for the result, is caught in a BroadcastReceiver.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution' means DNS resolution does not appear to be working.

Comment: What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Depends, where do you host your site/app? If it is a server you can control, check if you can curl or ping www.google.com. Otherwise, complain to your hoster.

Comment: Will do that! Because I didn't change anything on my code and it had been working fine, I just noticed this morning that the entire code is not working. IT must be my host